# Pandas compare one column values to another column to get new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
id1  id2  name
11   23   abc xyz 2
22   24   def pqr 5
33   22   qaz wsx 55
44   55   qwe rty 43
55   29   asd zxc 7
```

Now I want to create a new column which will contain `name[0]` of ith row, where `id1[i] == id2[j]`. So in the end I will have:

```
id1  id2  name        identifier
11   23   abc xyz 2   
22   24   def pqr 5   def
33   22   qaz wsx 55  def
44   55   qwe rty 43  asd
55   29   asd zxc 7   asd
```

So far, I tried this to get the required id:

```
df['identifier'] = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    j = df.index[df['id1'] == row['id2']]
```

Not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it like so:

```
df['identifier'] = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        j = df.index[df['id1'] == row['id2']].to_list()[0]
        df.at[j, 'identifier'] = df.iloc[j]['FamilyName'].split(" ")[0]
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could do:

```
# extract first word and set id1 as name
s = df.set_index('id1')['name'].str.extract('^(\S+)', expand=False)
# compute the identifiers
s2 = df['id2'].map(s).fillna(df['id1'].map(s))
# mask the unique identifiers
mask = s2.groupby(s2).transform('size').gt(1)

df2 = df.assign(identifier=s2[mask])
```

output:

```
   id1  id2        name identifier
0   11   23   abc xyz 2        NaN
1   22   24   def pqr 5        def
2   33   22  qaz wsx 55        def
3   44   55  qwe rty 43        asd
4   55   29   asd zxc 7        asd
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a new column by using `loc()` and use this conditional statement `df['id1'] == df['id2']` on `"name"` column, and create a new called `'identifier`' and invoke `pandas.Series.str.split` method to separate strings (by each whitespace):

```py
df['identifier']=df.loc[(df['id1']==df['id2']),'name'].str.split()
```

Now, is probably that will appear some `NaN` values on this new column, then I replace to `' '`, this allows to indexing first value on the **string** list

```py
df['identifier'].fillna(' ', inplace=True)
df['identifier']=df['identifier'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: This doesn't work as `df['id1']==df['id2']` always returns False for given example